# How do I get the last n rows matching the last three unique values in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, unique

I want to get the last `n` rows which have a `Value` which matches any of the last three unique values in the `Value` column.

Here's an example DataFrame:

```
df = {'Features':['A','A','A','A','C','C','C','C','B','B','B','B'],'Date':['1/3/2023','1/3/2022','1/3/2022','1/3/2021','1/3/2024','5/8/2020','5/8/2021','5/8/2022','6/1/2020','6/1/2019','5/8/2023','5/8/2023'],
'Value':[2,9,4,7,4,5,7,8,0,3,9,9]}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)

   Features Date    Value
0   A   1/3/2023    2
1   A   1/3/2022    9
2   A   1/3/2022    4
3   A   1/3/2021    7
4   C   1/3/2024    4
5   C   5/8/2020    5
6   C   5/8/2021    7
7   C   5/8/2022    8
8   B   6/1/2020    0
9   B   6/1/2019    3
10  B   5/8/2023    9
11  B   5/8/2023    9
```

For instance, for the sample data above the last three unique values are `0, 3, 9` with which the last *four* rows match, so the desired output would be:

```
7   B   6/1/2020    0
8   B   6/1/2019    3
9   B   5/8/2023    9
10  B   5/8/2023    9
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You say "last three" but your example of your desired output includes four records.

Comment: It's the last 3 _values_ I believe. 0, 3 and 9 (there are just 2 rows with 9) @blorgon

Comment: I mean, they say very explicitly: "last three unique *rows*" three separate times, once in the title, twice in the body. I'm inclined to believe OP made a mistake.

Comment: "I want to get the rows of 0,3 and 9" which is 4 rows. I could be wrong. Only OP can confirm.

Comment: @blorgon sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

For unique values based on the `Value` column,

```py
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset='Value').tail(3)
  Features      Date  Value
7        B  6/1/2020      0
8        B  6/1/2019      3
9        B  5/8/2023      9
```

Comment: No problem, this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remove duplicates rows, get the 3rd index from the end (`-3`) and slice your dataframe from this index to the end (`:`)

```
>>> df.loc[df.loc[~df.duplicated('Value')].index[-3]:]

   Features      Date  Value
7         B  6/1/2020      0
8         B  6/1/2019      3
9         B  5/8/2023      9
10        B  5/8/2023      9
```

Comment: @HenryEcker. So should I subset the `duplicated` to 'Value' only or all columns?

Comment: I don't know, seems it's same for this example. "to get the last three unique rows of __Value__ column" made me thing that it's only Value dependent. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We can try taking the last 3 [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) values from the `value` column:

```
df['Value'].unique()
# [2 4 7 5 8 0 3 9]
```

The last three unique values are 0, 3 and 9.

We can then filter the DataFrame to include only rows with those values:

```
df[df['Value'].isin(df['Value'].unique()[-3:])]
```

```
   Features      Date  Value
7         B  6/1/2020      0
8         B  6/1/2019      3
9         B  5/8/2023      9
10        B  5/8/2023      9
```